# Based on 2 columns data, verify another column has variable

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

I sorry for the title.  I am trying to do this without helper columns if possible. Here is the situation:

[image]

When there is Apple and Orange in `columns B and C`, I need to ensure at least one  Cat in `column D` within the limits of unique variable of A.  So for T001162929, I need to have a Cat in `D1:D3`.

When there is Apple and Banana in `columns B and C`, I need to ensure there is at least on Bird, Cat, and Dog in `column D` within the limits of the unique variable of A. So for T001172659, I need to have at least one Bird, Cat, and Dog in `D5:D10`.

I started going down the `INDEX/MATCH` path, but can't figure this one out.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Look into COUNTIFS()

Comment: ok... On it, thx!

Comment: I am trying COUNTIFS() and probably could go this route it will probably need a few helper columns.

Comment: Are you trying to verify that you already have these conditions met using the data as presented? And if so, how do you want the results returned?

Comment: Can you specify the individual ranges e.g. D1:D3 in the formula?

Comment: Thx for your thoughts.  I have a ton of data that i need to confirm has certain things.  So for T001162929, I want to check make sure it has a Bird, Cat and Dog in column D based on having both Apple and Banana in columns B and C.  If it does not, I need to flag it for further review.   I hope this makes sense.